# iPython local install error

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install iPython and iPython notebook as a local install:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$BINF" ipython[notebook]
```

and receive the error

```
re: jinja2 installing in /usr/local/lib:

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2'
```

Can I direct pip to install this in `$BINF/lib`?

I do not have sudo, but I do have admin on the BINF tree.

Comment: Have you tried installing stuff into a separate `virtualenv`? Maybe virtualenvs is not what you want but it could solve your issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what `$BINF` is, but would the `--user` option help? That will install things under your home directory, in a location that Python automatically knows to look at. If not, pip appears to take a `--root <dir>` option.